# Python closing file

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to close file, but I can't do that, because I use csv.writer, how can I close file? python

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    time = dt.now().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    self.file = csv.writer(open(file_path, 'w'))
    self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manually closing the file, it is a good practice to wrap the function under `with`.

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    time = dt.now().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        self.file = csv.writer(file)
        self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor your code so that the code captures the file handle; then you can easily call `.close()` on it when you are done.

But a better solution still is to use `with open`, which is also robust against exceptions. The file will be closed even if the code inside the `with` block raises an exception which is caught somewhere in the code which calls your function.

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    time = dt.now().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    with open(file_path, 'w')  as handle:
        self.file = csv.writer(handle)
        self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

However, perhaps you want to just `open` at this time, and save `self.handle` so that you can close it later - the name and design of your function suggests that you want to continue writing data to `self.file`, and only then `self.handle.close()`

Ideally, perhaps you would like to make a `spider_writer` object which is *also* a context manager, so that you can say

```
with spider_writer(filename) as writer:
     writer.write(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the `open()` first

```py
f = open(file_path, 'w')
self.file = csv.writer(f)
self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
f.close()
```

Or use context manager via `with`. You don't need to manually close in this case

```py
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    self.file = csv.writer(f)
    self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to close a file is by using the `with` statement. This ensures that the file is closed when the block inside the `with` statement is exited so you do not need to explicitly call the close() method and it is internally done.
For example:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as ff:
    self.file = csv.writer(ff)
    self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "with" keyword which htakes care of closing the file. With a little rewrite you get:

```
import csv

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        time = "12_00_00"
        file_path= f"test_{time}.csv"
    
        #file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    
        with open(file_path, 'w') as csv_file:
            self.file = csv.writer(csv_file)
            self.file.writerow(['Статус'.encode("utf-8"), 'Количество'.encode("utf-8")])
        
a=A()
spider = 'fasdfsafd'
a.open_spider(spider)
```

Furthermore I had to encode the strings you provided as they are not ascii. Using the clock time is something for you to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `f = open(file_path, 'w')` and then `csv.writer(f)`. Here is the code:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    time = dt.now().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    f = open(file_path, 'w')
    self.file = csv.writer(f)
    self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
    f.close()
```

Or you can use `self.f` instead of `f` to close the file later.

However there is another way. It is to use `with` construction. Here is how it works:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    # do something with the file f here
# here the file should be closed automatically
```

The reason why it works is that python calls `__enter__` method of `f` upon entering `with` construction (which does nothing) and then it calls `__exit__` method of `f` upon exiting `with` construction (which closes the file). Here is the code:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    time = dt.now().strftime(TIME_FORMAT)
    file_path = self.results_dir / FILE_NAME.format(time)
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        self.file = csv.writer(f)
        self.file.writerow(['Статус', 'Количество'])
```

The reason why you should use `with` is that it's exception-proof. That means that if an exception appears within `with` construction, it will close the file and raise the exception only after that. So the file will be closed even if something goes wrong while writing to that file.